# 'RAISERROR' must be declared

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER x AFTER INSERT ON itemtype 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    minn itemtype.PRICE%type;
BEGIN 
select MIN(itemtype.PRICE) into minn from itemtype;
IF (:new.PRICE > minn*4) then RAISERROR('Custom text');
END IF;
END;
/
```

I'm trying to create a trigger that raises an error when I try to insert a new entry into the `itemtype` with `itemtype.PRICE` column value is greater than 4 times the current low priced item on the table.

I get these compilation errors when I try to create the trigger.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------
5/31     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/31     PLS-00201: identifier 'RAISERROR' must be declared
```

I have also tried

```
    CREATE TRIGGER x AFTER INSERT ON itemtype 
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
        minn itemtype.PRICE%type;
    BEGIN 
    select MIN(itemtype.PRICE) into minn from itemtype;
    if (:new.PRICE > minn*4) then raise_application_error(-20010,'Too Expensive');
    END IF;
    END;
    /
```

which complies, but when i try to insert a new entry into the table I get theses errors saying my trigger fails.

```
    SQL> insert into itemtype(ITEMNUM,NAME,PICTURE,PRICE,BELONGSTO ) VALUES ('A11','The who knows','',10.99,'P');
    insert into itemtype(ITEMNUM,NAME,PICTURE,PRICE,BELONGSTO ) VALUES ('A11','The who knows','',10.99,'P')
                *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-04091: table USERNAME.ITEMTYPE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
    ORA-06512: at "USERNAME.X", line 5
    ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USERNAME.X'
```

Comment: I have also tried  RAISERROR('custom text', 10, 1);
and i get the same error

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020450/oracle-pl-sql-raise-user-defined-exception-with-custom-sqlerrm

Comment: I think you have something tagged wrong here. Your error references PL/SQL but this is tagged MySQL. Try RAISE. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/raise_statement.htm

Comment: @AndreiHirsu not really

Answer (score 0):

Try use PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in trigger.

Look my answer on this question:
[SQL trigger on delete mutating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621536/sql-trigger-on-delete-mutating-table/47621714#47621714)

Comment: please return feedback if my answer is solution for your question